# ¿Cómo puedo cambiarme desde vba a una ventana de otra aplicación abierta?

Tags: java, vba

Tengo una macro VBA ejecutándose, en excel, pero necesito en un momento del proceso pasar a una aplicación Java desktop que interactúa con los datos de la fila seleccionada en excel y me devuelve un valor, el paso de valores me funciona bien, pero tengo que cambiar manual desde excel a Java y viceversa, por ejemplo con alt+Tab.

Necesito ver en pantalla mi aplicación Java, en ella se hacen procesos de tratamiento de imágenes.

La idea que he tratado es que al seleccionar una columna específica de la tabla excel, la macro me cambié automáticamente a la aplicación Java, en Java tendré que hacer algo parecido para regresar al excel mediante un evento.

Todo me funciona excepto que debo alternar manualmente entre las aplicaciones excel y Java. Con dos monitores funciona bien, pero este programa se estará ejecutando en un entorno con poco espacio .

Comment: Hola @GreydelPerezFerrer, necesito como tu pasar de excel a una aplicacion java datos, podrias indicarme como pasas desde excel al java.. estoy busca que te busca y no encuentro, con sendkeys alt+tab no me funciona...y como escribiste que lo hacias... gracias,

Comment: y perdon... y moverme por unos menus de la aplicacion java, mil gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el objeto `Windows` para ello, tiene la propiedad `.Activate` para poner la ventana elegida en el objeto en primer plano. Por ejemplo `Windows(Titulo de tu ventana).Activate`. Para más información puedes leer la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.window)

Comment: Gracias, he logrado pasar de excel a Java sin problemas, por algún motivo el procedimiento appactivate no me funcionaba como debería y al invocarlo desde un objeto previamente creado me ha funcionado. No exactamente como me dices, he creado un objeto vacío, luego he instanciado a la clase y al fin he logrado activar la ventana.

Comment: Alguna idea sobre cómo hacer el regreso, o sea desde Java a excel? Lo que hago ahora mismo es minimizar Java y que el usuario de click en el excel visible para activarlo.

Comment: @GreydelPerezFerrer para qué necesitas hacer tal cosa? Excel lo puedes controlar al 100% sin tocar ventanas. `.Select` y `.Activate` en excel son prácticas poco recomendables.

Comment: Estoy realizando una bella aplicación de reconocimiento de imagenes en Java, pero el cliente aún es reacio a salirse de excel dónde está su zona de confort,  por eso las dos aplicaciones. En excel, cuando el usuario clickea en una columna específica se activa la aplicación de Java, está interactúa un poco con el usuario y luego devuelve un número a la celda activa de excel. En este momento desde excel activo el Java, ahora desde Java estoy tratando de activar el excel sin cerrar ninguna de las aplicaciones.

Comment: pues desde java no sabría decirte cómo activar excel...  desde excel puedes hacer `ThisWorkbook.Activate` lo único que tendrías que esperar a que java termine...

Comment: La verdad es que no regresa, he puesto un temporizador que espera a que exista la respuesta en la celda correspondiente y haga beep y he probado appactivate, se queda parpadeando pero no se muestra, con la opción thisworkbook no hace nada. El beep funciona y me sirve de medidor para saber que entra al procedimiento.

Comment: pues quizá un `SendKeys` para hacer un alt+tab @GreydelPerezFerrer?

Comment: Gracias amigo. La verdad es que el regreso de java a excel se me ha hecho más complicado y aunque lo logro en un 99% de las veces no siempre lo hace correctamente. Tendrá que servir de ese modo. La limitante con sendkeys alt+Tab es que el usuario no puede estarse moviendo a otras ventanas, pero parece que es eso o nada. El programa Java está conectado a una cámara IP y no puedo ir abriendo y cerrando el programa cada vez, por eso no puedo simplemente esperar que Java termine para regresar a excel. De nuevo gracias por el tiempo.

Comment: @GreydelPerezFerrer podrías hacer una workaround para esperar que java acabe. Podrías hacer que java cree un .txt al finalizar y obligar a excel a entrar en bucle buscando dicho .txt hasta que lo encuentre. Una vez encontrado, lo elimina y continua con el proceso.

Comment: Eso es precisamente lo que hago, además es desde ese txt desde donde tomo el resultado de Java. Tengo una revisión cada milisegundos hasta que el txt se actualiza, copio el resultado a una celda bien. Pero lo difícil es que  cuando trato de devolver el foco a  excel algunas veces se queda parpadeando  y no se muestra. Que es un workaround? discupa.